# Expanded notification

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-notification

I have a notification that i want to be displayed immediately after that´s created.

my code right now:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(WearRunActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("distance", distance);
    myIntent.putExtra("time", chronometer.getText());
    myIntent.putExtra("pace", pace);
    myIntent.putExtra("speed", speedAc);
    myIntent.putExtra("lSteps", leftSteps);
    myIntent.putExtra("rSteps", rightSteps);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    //WearRunActivity.this.startActivityIfNeeded(myIntent, 1);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.card_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("REPORT")
                    .setContentText(chronometer.getText())
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            getResources(), R.drawable.card_icon))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notification_manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    notification_manager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
```

With this code, the notification is created but it is not displayed automatically on the screen. I need to swipe through all the pending notifications to search for it. What I want is that this notification is displayed on the screen automatically after it is created, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foud a way!
When building the notification add the line **.setOngoing(True)** so when the notification is sent, it will be on top of all the pending notifications and will be displayed on the screen.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.card_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Report")
                    .setContentText(chronometer.getText())
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            getResources(), R.drawable.card_background_blur))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```